# Is there a way to pack all simulation results in to one file?

Tags: blend-files, packed-data

So I have a simulation that I will do on one computer then move to another to do the rendering.The reason is because computer A is faster at simulation but bad at rendering computer B is horrible at simulation but is great at rendering. So would there be a way to put all of the simulation files together(Packing doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't pack the simulation into the .blend file, but you can save the blend file and the baked simulations on to the same folder and move them to a different computer for rendering.

Just make sure you use relative paths //